# Unable to import Pandas in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS Lambda and I want to run code on Lambda for a machine learning API. The functions that I want to run on Lambda are, in summary, one to read some csv files to create a pandas dataFrame and search in it and the other to run some pickled machine learning models through requests from a Flask application. To do this, I need to import pandas, joblib and possibly scikit-learn which are compatible with Amazon Linux. I am using a Windows machine.

In general, I am going with the approach of using Lambda's layers by uploading zip files. Of course, since Lambda has a pre-built layer with SciPy and Numpy so I will not import them. If I import them, I will exceed Lambda's layer limit anyway.
To be more specific, I have done the following:

- Downloaded and extracted linux-compatible versions of the libraries listed  above. For example: From this    [link](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files) I have downloaded    "pandas-0.25.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl" and unzipped to a    folder.
- The unzipped libraries are in the following directory:

  > lambda_layers\python\lib\python3.7\site-packages
- They are zipped into a file and uploaded onto S3 Bucket for creating a layer.

I imported the packages:

```py
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
```

I got the following error from Lambda:

> {
>     "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.",
>     "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
>   }

Comment: Can you try this: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers , there is a pandas layer I haven't tested that is publicly available. arn:aws:lambda:<region>:113088814899:layer:Klayers-python37-pandas:<version>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folder structure should be standard, you can also use Docker to create the zipped Linux compatible library and upload it in AWS Lambda layers. Below are the tested commands to create the zipped library for AWS Lambda layer:

1. Create and navigate to a directory :

   ```
   $mkdir aws1
   $cd aws1
   ```
2. Write the below commands in Dockerfile and exit by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> :

   ```
   $cat> Dockerfile

   FROM amazonlinux:2017.03  
   RUN yum -y install git \ 
       python36 \  
       python36-pip \  
       zip \  
       && yum clean all  
   RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \  
       && python3 -m pip install boto3
   ```
3. You can provide any name for the image :

   ```
   $docker build -t pythn1/lambda .
   ```
4. Run the image :

   ```
   $docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/var/task pythn1/lambda:latest bash
   ```
5. Specify the package which you want to zip, in requirements.txt and exit by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> :

   ```
   $ cat > requirements.txt
   pandas
   sklearn
   ```
6. You can try using correct file structure (`/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`) here, but I did not test it yet :

   ```
   $pip install -r requirements.txt -t /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
   ```
7. Navigate to the below directory :

   ```
   $cd var/task
   ```
8. Create a zip file :

   ```
   $ zip -r ./layers.zip /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
   ```

You should be able to see a layers.zip file in aws1 folder. If you provide the correct folder structure while installing, then the below steps are not required. But, with the folder structure I used, below commands are required :

9. Unzip layers.zip.
10. Exit Docker or open a new terminal and navigate to the folder where you unzipped the file. Unzipped file will be in the folder structure `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`.
11. Copy these files to the correct folder structure :

    ```
    $ cp -r ./python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
    ```
12. Zip them again :

    ```
    $ zip -r ./lib_python.zip ./python
    ```
13. Upload the zip file to the layer, and add that layer to your Lambda function. Also, make sure that you select the right running environment while creating the layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have followed some guides with Docker but they did not work for me. Still, this is one of the more popular and up-to-date solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

Following this document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path, you should zip python\lib\python3.7\site-packages\pandas (and other dependencies) folder for your python layers.

Make sure you add the layer to your function and follow the documentation for the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answers that were given, just posting my own answer (that I found after a whole day looking) here for reference purpose.

I followed this [guide](https://github.com/AkshayaDev/install-python-37-aws-ec2) and also this [guide](https://hackersandslackers.com/using-pandas-with-aws-lambda/).

In summary, the steps to what I did are:

1. Connect to my Amazon EC2 instance (running on Linux) through ssh. I
   wanted to deploy an application on Beanstalk so it was already up for
   me anyway.
2. Follow the steps in the first guide to install python 3.7.
   Follow the steps in the second guide to install the libraries. One of
   the key notes is not to install with `pip install -t` since that 
   will lead to the libraries and the C extensions not built.
3. Zip the directory found in `python\lib\python3.7\site-packages\` as
   mentioned by the answers here (although I did follow the directory
   guide in my first attempts)
4. Get the file from EC2 instance through
   FileZilla.
5. Follow the Lambda layers guide and it is done.

Comment: I followed these steps to create a layer for a ML library (xgboost); where the .so file is ~410MB & zip'd version of the library is about 150MB. Created a bucket and dropped the zipped version there and trying use s3 link in a lambda layer to use it in a function; it complains "Failed to create layer version: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes".  What is the best way out here?

Comment: AWS Lambda layers are very limited in size (250MB max) so I do not think that this is the recommended and efficient way of deploying a model by now. Back when I asked this question I took advantage of the pre-built layers offered by Lambda which contain scipy, numpy, etc and it was a huge help since they consumed a lot of space. I would suggest looking for a guide for SageMaker instead.

Comment: trying a solution as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235753/4149861), which is copying zip of the libs from s3 to to /tmp dir of lambda runtime and updating sys.path (in addition to using layers)