# Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes - AWS Lambda Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have tried to upload my application using servless/lambda function AWS, but i got this issue:

> An error occurred: AppLambdaFunction - Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 8ea0d887-5743-4db1-96cd-6c5efa57b081).

What is the best way to resolve it?

Look my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ethereumjs-tx": "^1.3.7",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.4.52",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "helmet": "^3.16.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^2.3.0",
    "serverless": "^1.48.2",
    "serverless-http": "^1.9.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^4.9.4",
    "truffle": "^5.1.9",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.2.5-rc.0"
  },
```

Serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: v1
  region: us-east-1
  timeout: 30
  memorySize: 512
  package:
    excludeDevDependencies: true
    exclude:
      - .git/**
      - .vscode/**        
      - venv/**

functions:
  app:  
    handler: handler.run
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Comment: i put on "exclude" :

   exclude:
      - node_modules/**
      - .git/**
      - .vscode/**        
      - venv/**

But didnt exclude the node_modules folder... ( and i dont know if it will resolve the issue, because i need to have this dependences on S3)

Comment: Any layers in your lambda? They count towards the size limit as well.

Comment: `"aws-sdk": "^2.4.52"` unless you need a specific version of aws sdk, do not include this in your dependencies as the aws sdk is already available in the lambda environment without you having to install it. Put it in your dev dependencies instead.

Comment: I don't use many libraries so don't recognise most of the ones you have listed, but is "serverless*" to do with the serverless transformation of your template, i.e. required on your side but not in your final product? If so those should be moved to dev dependencies as well. Anything you don't need in your final lambda should be in dev dependencies.

Comment: As @404 says, move the unneeded dependencies (at least aws-sdk and serverless*) out of dependencies and into devDependencies.

Comment: Guys, thanks so much! I did it, putting some packages that is not necessary on deploy to devDependencies, and now its worked!!! Tkss everybody!

Answer (score 46):

Use the directive `exclude` at your serverless.yml file. In case of Python, I've been used it as follows:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - venv/**
```

The build process will exclude them from the build before sending to AWS.

Tip I got [in this issue at Github](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/343). The documentation for this directive is [detailed here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/packaging/#package-configuration).

Comment: Worked here and saved my night! :)

Comment: `package.exclude` is soon to be deprecated and *patterns* should be used instead according to the [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#NEW_PACKAGE_PATTERNS)

Comment: how do my packages get loaded then...?

Comment: use requirements.txt along with

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true
    slim: true

Comment: @0xD1x0n yes exactly, so how did you resolve this?

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks

Answer (score 4):

Recently i faced the same issue, my total package size was more than 40mbs and it was also including the venv (python virtual environment) folder that resides in the project directory. I excluded it and build size got reduced to 16 mbs. and the project was deployed successfully. I added the following in serverless.yaml

```
package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!venv/**'
    - '!apienv/**'
    - '!__pycache__/**'
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue once I started depending on the `boto3` library.

After trying lots of different things, I learned that this package [comes pre-installed](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1629#issuecomment-448783754) with the AWS Python runtime so you can either leave the dependency undeclared or make it a dev dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You can use module bundlers to package the code.

#### Using module bundlers such as webpack

You can consider using plugins like `serverless-webpack`. The `serverless-webpack` plugin is using `webpack` to build the project and it will only include the bare minimum files required to run your application. It will not include the entire node_modules directory. so that your deployment package will be smaller.

#### a note about using of Lambda layers

Like others mentioned, you can use the layers and move some of the libraries and code to the layer. Layers are mainly used to share code between functions. The unzipped deployed package including layers cannot exceed 250MB.

hope this helps.

References:

https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

Answer (score 2):

I've had success resolving this error message using the `serverless-esbuild` plugin, and configuring it as follows in `serverless.yml`:

```
service: service_name
frameworkVersion: '3'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild

custom:
  esbuild:
    bundle: true
    minify: false
    sourcemap: true
    exclude: 'aws-sdk'
    target: node14
    define:
      'require.resolve': undefined
    platform: node
    concurrency: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71920166/11922567)

You can deploy a `Lambda function` using a `Docker image` and it bypasses this problem, allowing a function with its dependencies to be as large as 10 gb.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **exclude** under **package** is deprecated. We can use pattern to remove node_modules.

Example to remove files in the serverless.yml

```
...remaining props
package:
  patterns:
    - '!.git/**'
    - '!test/**'
    - '!e2e/**'
    - '!src/**'
    - '!node_modules/**'
```

[Deprecation for exclude](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#NEW_PACKAGE_PATTERNS) and
[Pattern](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/#patterns)

Comment: i tried this but get an error ```Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir```

Comment: Can you give more detailed information to debug on the error? Or we can open separate stackoverflow thread to fix your error!

Answer (score -1):

You can load larger packages into AWS Lambda indirectly using s3:

- Load your package into a bucket/key on S3
- In the Lambda console choose Function Code -> Code Entry Type -> Upload a file from S3

Comment: I don't think you can have a package over 250MB, no matter where you put it. Serverless is probably uploading it to S3 first anyway.

Comment: That is the limit, you're right.   250MB is a lot.  They must be pulling in a lot of extra stuff.

Comment: If 250MB is the limit & if I required to use machine learning libs like xgboost, what is the way out?  The zipped version of xgboost is about 150 MB and unable create a layer that has only this library

Comment: @NBhat you should look for another alternative if you can't fit everything in a lambda, some limits are soft (you can request an increase by talking to AWS) while others (like deployment file size) are not https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

Comment: Refer to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235753/4149861); I'm using a combination of both: aws layers (for scipy numpy pandas that's within limit) & extracting xgboost lib into /tmp/pkg/ directory along with adding /tmp/pkg to sys.path. I was successful with this approach.