# Can't use OpenCV-Python in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.8

I've been trying to get OpenCV into an S3 bucket and then assign it to a lambda layer.

Theres very little about this online and what I have seen hasn't worked.

I've managed to use docker with the amazon linux environment, and followed this tutorial. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/

I've added setuptools, wheel and opencv-python==4.4.0.42 to the requirements.txt file.

setuptools and wheel because of an earlier error where the recommendation was to include these as they need updating, even though I have updated them. But it works with them, so who knows.

Created the docker image which I've zipped and put in an S3 bucket.

I keep getting
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
when I run it though.

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to add a bunch of dependencies to your layer. Below are the steps that I've used
for opencv_python on lambda.

### 1. On local workstation (terminal window 1)

```
mkdir /tmp/mylayer && cd /tmp/mylayer

echo opencv-python==4.4.0.42 > ./requirements.txt
```

### 2. On local workstation (terminal window 2)

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/mylayer:/mylayer  lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 bash
```

The above command will put you into the docker container.

Inside the container:

```
cd /mylayer

pip install --no-deps -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ -r requirements.txt

yum install -y mesa-libGL

cp -v /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.7.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libGLX.so.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libGLdispatch.so.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so.1.2.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libGLESv2.so.2.1.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
cp -v /lib64/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0 /mylayer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/
```

### 3. On local workstation again (terminal window 1)

Pack the `python` folder into `mylayer.zip`.

```
zip -r -9 mylayer.zip python
```

### In AWS console

4. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`.
5. Add AWS provide SciPy layer `AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x` and your own layer with cv2 into your function.

So you will have **two layers** in your function.

6. Perform basic test of the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import cv2

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    print(dir(csv))
```

The function executes correctly (partial printout shown).

```
slation3D', 'exp', 'extractChannel', 'fastAtan2', 'fastNlMeansDenoising', 'fastNlMeansDenoisingColored', 'fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti', 'fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti', 'fillConvexPoly', 'fillPoly', 'filter2D', 'filterHomographyDecompByVisibleRefpoints', 'filterSpeckles', 'find4QuadCornerSubpix', 'findChessboardCorners', 'findChessboardCornersSB', 'findChessboardCornersSBWithMeta', 'findCirclesGrid', 'findContours', 'findEssentialMat', 'findFundamentalMat', 'findHomography', 'findNonZero', 'findTransformECC', 'fisheye', 'fitEllipse', 'fitEllipseAMS', 'fitEllipseDirect', 'fitLine', 'flann', 'flann_Index', 'flip', 'floodFill', 'gemm', 'getAffineTransform', 'getBuildInformation', 'getCPUFeaturesLine', 'getCPUTickCount', 'getDefaultNewCameraMatrix', 'getDerivKernels', 'getFontScaleFromHeight', 'getGaborKernel', 'getGaussianKernel', 'getHardwareFeatureName', 'getNumThreads', 'g
```

Comment: Marcin, I love you!! You have no idea how many days I've been struggling with this. Just used this and it worked without any errors. Thank you!

Comment: OMG you are my new best friend!

Comment: @PaulRaupach Glad my answer was helpful:-)

Comment: The `libGLES*.so.*` files didn't get installed for me, but it seems to work without them.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I spent days trying to figure this out!!!

Comment: I spent three hours on the three garbage tutorials at the top of the Google search rankings and this worked instantly. Thanks so much! You should turn this into a blog post so that it drowns out the other nonsense out there wasting countless hours of people's lives.

Comment: @Marcin you're killing it lately! I have a similar issue and your solution wasn't able to solve it. Take a look if you have time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448962/aws-lambda-unable-to-find-libgl-so-package-while-using-moderngl-glcontext

Comment: I've followed these steps to create the layer which works fine, but when I use the layer in a sam-build the libGL.so.1 is still missing (i checked the zip and its definately there..) Also the sam build is copying most of the other.so files from opencv_pyhon.libs. Any ideas?

Comment: @Litrico Difficult to say. You can make new question for that. Or can cook at lambda containers. They make installing dependencies for lambda easier and give you 10GB of space.

Comment: Tbh I was planning on looking into the containers, but haven't read into it yet though, I'll create a new post as well on Monday, tnx for the response.

Comment: Found out that the problem was that i still had opencv-python==4.4.0.42 in my lambda, this caused the layer dependencies to be overwritten and thus not used!

Comment: I am still getting the libgl.so.1 not found error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Although this solution does work (adding dependency layers), this doesn't get around the hard size limit of 250MB. Luckily AWS have added support for Lamda's to run container images - see my answer here: [How to increase the maximum size of the AWS lambda deployment package (RequestEntityTooLargeException)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632009/how-to-increase-the-maximum-size-of-the-aws-lambda-deployment-package-requesten/66243436#66243436)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the error

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libGL.so.1: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory" error,

Install the

> opencv-python-headless

instead of

> opencv-python

The lambda is throwing this error about LibGL because lambda functions does not support any UI and opencv comes with some UI stuff. The "headless" module does not include the GUI that comes with opencv, which resolves the error you see.

Check out these videos:

1. how to create opencv layers with a ubuntu ec2 instance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQBT8vVRkAg&ab_channel=SrceCde
2. how to solve the LibGL problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2rWypy8OaM&ab_channel=SrceCde

Comment: This worked for me, installing opencv on a Lamda function with Docker and Python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

using `lambci/lambda:build-python3.6` instead of `lambci/lambda:build-python3.8` does fix the `libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file` error for me since `build-python3.8` reduce its size by [removing some native dependencies](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda/issues/318)