# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'cv2.cv2'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

After I added `import cv2` will got this errors, anyone face this issue before? please

[image]

Comment: have you setup cv2 with your function?

Comment: what you mean setup???

Comment: `cv2` is `opencv-python`. So did you set it up? By default lambda does not come pre-installed with `opencv-python`. So that's why you are getting error.

Comment: For that, I already setup, but don know got this errors

Comment: Probably you setup up incorrectly?

Comment: I not sure, how to check I setup incorrectly?? I created a layer using amazon s3, I upload the file in s3 and paste the Amazon S3 link URL. After I create a function and import cv2 in function code

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016819/cant-use-opencv-python-in-aws-lambda/64019186#64019186) is working procedure to setup cv2 as layer.

Comment: I m not using docker