# OpenCV in AWS Lambda container image

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, opencv, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a docker image which will be deployed as a function on AWS Lambda. Able to build and test the image successfully but facing an issue when I try to import OpenCV in the function.

I do not face this issue when I remove the import statement from app.py

**The error I am facing -**

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
```

**My Dockerfile -**

```
# Define custom function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM python:3.9 as build-image

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY app/* ${FUNCTION_DIR}

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the function's dependencies
RUN pip install \
    --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
        awslambdaric


FROM python:3.9

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

**My requirements.txt -**

```
mediapipe<=0.8.3.1
numpy<=1.19.4
opencv-python<=4.4.0.46
boto3<=1.17.64
```

**My app.py**

```
import cv2

def handler(event, context):
    return cv2.__version__
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016819/cant-use-opencv-python-in-aws-lambda

Comment: Not quite related. In that post they’re installing it in a lambda layer it seems.

Comment: They include steps to install and locate libGL.so.1, which is what you are missing.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, managed to solve it using the solution provided in this question - [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue getting the same error when trying to use a mediapipe container. pip installing python-opencv-headless solved the issue for me, I did not need to install any additional dependencies.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install mediapipe opencv-python-headless --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and managed to solve it and tested on AWS Lambda container image. This is how my Dockerfile looks (as on 20 Nov 2023)

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

COPY ./ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN yum update -y
#used to get rid of Error ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
RUN yum install mesa-libGL -y
RUN yum install libglvnd-glx -y
RUN yum install gcc openssl-devel wget tar -y

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747786/aws-eb-opencv-python-web-from-cv2-import) I added the CentOS (yum) install of opencv and opencv-python. So my Dockerfile looks as follows

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:latest
# FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm #- use this for non Lambda deploy

COPY requirements.txt ./

# install packages
RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ make cmake opencv opencv-python-headless  pkgconfig poppler-cpp-devel
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /data

# copy all code and lambda handler
COPY lambda_function.py ./

# run lambda handler
CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"]
```

Note how I've put the installs at the top so we don't have lengthy (160sec in this case) full rebuilds every time we change something before them.

I'm importing *dlib* as well as *opencv* on an M2 Macbook in preparation for running on an ARM64 AWS Lambda using containers. So we need the *gcc* and *make* tools too.

Answer (score -1):

Managed to solve it by adding these to the Dockerfile -

```
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

New Dockerfile looks like this -

```
# Define custom function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM python:3.9 as build-image

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    ffmpeg \ 
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY app/* ${FUNCTION_DIR}

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the function's dependencies
RUN pip install \
    --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
        awslambdaric


FROM python:3.9

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```