# aws eb opencv-python "web: from .cv2 import"

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

in aws-eb I am deployed an application -django- and there was no error on that process. Health is green and **OK** but page is giving **Internal Server Error**. so I checked the logs and saw the below error.

```
... web: from .cv2 import  
... web: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

while installing requirements.txt on deployment process opencv must be installed. because it includes `opencv-python==4.5.5.64`
so I not quite sure what is the above error pointing at.

and helpers.py this is how I am import it.

```
import requests
import cv2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libGL.so is installed with the package libgl1, `pip3 install opencv-python` is not sufficient here.

Connect the aws via ssh and run;

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1
```

Or even better, consider using docker containers for the project and add the installation commands to the Dockerfile.

Also, as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66473309/12416058 suggests, *Package python3-opencv includes all system dependencies of OpenCV.* so installing it may prevent further errors.

To install python3-opencv;

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To install in Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```